# How to add/delete textfields in PHP form

Tags: php, forms

I'm new to PHP. I'm creating a dynamic web page where I have to create a dynamic web page such that the textfield welcome notes should have add and delete options to get multiple textfields.

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'WelcomeNotes1'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'WelcomeNotes',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'WelcomeNotes'); ?>
    </div>
```

In the above textfield I want to have add/delete textfields. When I click on add options, another field should be added and when I click on delete field should be deleted.
Finally when I save it all this has to form json string and stored.
Input for textfield is

```
Textfield1 : Hello
Textfield2 : Hi
```

**Result to be : Hello:Hi**
How can I achieve this

Comment: You are going to have to use javascript to do this.

Comment: @zessx I tried with jquery, the code did not work at all and hangs. I used a plugin from github

Comment: @Ray Anythings is fine

Comment: I guess you can do this only with `javascript`

Comment: It will be grateful if someone can suggest me

Answer (score 0):

This just isn't a good fit for PHP. PHP is server-side, meaning that if you're building the form with PHP it would require a refresh every time you add or remove an item. Javascript/jQuery is a better fit. You will still process the form using PHP of course.